# how BeautifulSoup get the content inside a span?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to parse fixture contents from a website I managed to parse Match column but facing difficulty in parsing date and time column.

My program

```
import re
import pytz
import requests
import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from espncricinfo.exceptions import MatchNotFoundError, NoScorecardError
from espncricinfo.match import Match

bigbash_article_link = "http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/series/1128817.html?template=fixtures"

r = requests.get(bigbash_article_link)
bigbash_article_html = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(bigbash_article_html, "html.parser")


bigbash1_items = soup.find_all("span",{"class": "fixture_date"})
bigbash_items = soup.find_all("span",{"class": "play_team"})
bigbash_article_dict = {}
date_dict = {}

for div in bigbash_items:
    a = div.find('a')['href']
    bigbash_article_dict[div.find('a').string] = a
print(bigbash_article_dict)
for div in bigbash1_items:
    a = div.find('span').string
    date_dict[div.find('span').string] = a
print(date_dict)
```

When I execute this I get   print(bigbash_article_dict) output, but print(date_dict) gives me error, how can I parse date and time content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow your code, you want to get the content inside the tag span.
So you should using  "div.contents" to get the contents of span.

And your question should be how BeautifulSoup get the content inside a span.

```
eg.
    div= <span class="fixture_date">
    Thu Feb 22
                            </span>
    div.contents[0].strip()= Thu Feb 22 
    ------------



for div in bigbash1_items:
        print("div=",div)    
        print("div.contents[0].strip()=",div.contents[0].strip(),"\r\n------------\r\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Elements with class `fixture_date` don't have a `<span>`, they are the span. You can get the data from them directly.

So instead of this:

```
div.find('span').string
```

You can do this:

```
div.string
```

From the structure of the website, this would return the date on odd iterations (1, 3, ..) and time on even iterations (2, 4, ..).

Oh and I'd advice you to make the variable name meaningful, so rename `div` to `span`.
Because in your code, all `div` variables actually contain `<span>` tags ;)